# Cannot upload file to form

Tags: firefox, upload, forms

I am trying to submit a file to a form [here](https://www.skyairline.com/chile/formularios/contactanos). There is a button called `Browse ...`, which when selected asks me for a local file. When I select a file, it starts loading but it fails. This is, the file does not show as uploaded. Message box remains as "No file selected."

[image: image here]

I called the company, and they say it works fine. I tried with Firefox and with Mirodi (another browser), with the same effect. I tried different files, small and large, to no avail. I tried Firefox in Safe Mode. I deleted cookies. Same problem. Don't know what else to do.

When I upload a file, the status bar says stuff like:

> Connected to s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
>   Performing a TLS handshake to s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
>   Sending request to s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
>   Waiting for s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.comm
>   Waiting for skyairline.inbenta.com

and then nothing happens.

Is this a local (my) problem? If so, what might be the problem?

Comment: Thanks. where exactly can I see the error in the developer's info? @Worthwelle Also, please write as answer.

Comment: @Worthwelle got it. i see. will call them now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Developer Console returns an error when uploading the file that implies this is an issue that the website developer would need to fix.

> ```
> SecurityError: Permission denied to access property "document" on cross-origin object contactanos:1
>     onload https://www.skyairline.com/chile/formularios/contactanos:1
> ```

Try sending them the error. It is possible that Firefox introduced stricter [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) (CORS) security since that website was developed

To get to this error in the Developer Console:

1. Open the website in Firefox.
2. Press <kbd>F12</kbd>.
3. Click *Browse…* and select your document. Click *Open*.
4. The bottom of the *Console* tab should now have the error listed:

   [image]